# What does ((LocalBinder)service) mean?

Tags: java, android

I got this code:

```
mBoundService = ((LocalService.LocalBinder)service).getService();
```

Could some nice guy explain what does this mean :((LocalService.LocalBinder)service)
And Could somebody please give some other example just like ((A)B).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a variable (service) and you convert it to type (LocalService.LocalBinder) then you get the service
this means that:

```
Service service;
LocalBinder binder = (LocalService.LocalBinder) service;
Service mBoundService = binder.getService();
```

try this it may help you

[**Reference**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399274/android-local-service-sample-bindservice-and-serviceconnection)

[**Example**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample)

Comment: Thank all you guys and especially danny-londonl.

Answer (score 4):

It's just casting. It's telling the compiler, "I know you only know about the value of this expression as type X, but I believe that at execution time it will be type Y. Check it for me at execution time, and then let me use it that way."

For example:

```
 Object x = getValueFromSomewhere();
 String text = (String) x; // I know x is a string reference really
 // Use text as a normal string reference
```

If your belief in the type involved is incorrect (e.g. if the value of `x` were a reference to an `Integer` instead of a `String`) then a [`ClassCastException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) is thrown.

See the [Java Inheritance Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for more information (or just search for "Java casting tutorial" to find lots of similar ones) or see [section 15.16 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16) for the details.

Comment: I like Jon Skeet too. Thank you very help.

Answer (score 0):

Local Binder means your activity should be binded to your application only. Please note that a service can be bound to other applications too. Whereas LocalService.LocalBinder allows your service to bound the application which contains the service.

Answer (score 0):

This statement means that "service" variable casts to type LocalService.LocalBinder.

Other sample:

```
double a=1.1f;
int i=(int)a;// you can't write int i=a;
```

Comment: That's not a great example, IMO, because numeric conversions are somewhat different to the reference cast used here.